# ssl through homestead box causing chrome to block the site

Tags: laravel, ssl, homestead

I've just started using homestead to try and do some laravel development on my windows machine (normally I work with valet on mac which does all this for you) and it looks like when I start a new homestead box (using "vagrant up") it automatically sets up ssl? And chrome is freaking out when trying to connect to the website because the certificate is invalid.

[image: chrome not allowing the ssl cert from homestead box]

I'm not sure how to get around this problem, how can I prevent the homestead box from trying to use ssl out of the box? Or get chrome to accept the cert that it's trying to provide?

I've tried downloading the certificate (crt file from /etc/nginx/ssl on the box) and installing it on my machine and then restarting chrome but I get the same error.

Comment: What TLD are you using for your homestead address? You can no longer use .dev or .app, as well as a few others. Use `.test` will work and then just include http:// at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @brianforan has pointed out in his comment, Google has decided for their own reasons that the latest versions of Chrome will no longer support development under the top level domain of ".dev". Chrome will assume that any .dev domain is automatically meant to run under SSL, and will redirect to SSL.

Use an alternate TLD for your site - I have a preference for .local or .localhost myself, but it's entirely up to you.